# Can we use two convolutional layers without a activation layer in middle of them?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Recently I trained a model for more than 100,000+ images. I forgot to use a activation layer in between two convolutional layers, but model trained better with good accuracy (99%). So I want to know is it a bad approach or can we do like this?

Comment: Did you use pooling between them? Or downsample using striding?

Comment: @jonnor I didn't use pooling between them. I used as follows                                      `model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=input_size))
 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since convolution is a linear operator, two consecutive convolutional layers can be realized by a single convolutional layer if there is no non-linear activation layer between them. Then, it is trivial to train one extra layer which has no positive effect on the representational power of your model.

Comment: I thought same thing, but there was a improvement in accuracy than using just one conv layer.

Comment: They should eventually converge to the (approximately) same solution unless it overfits. However, you should note that adding/eliminating a layer changes the model architecture and affect the whole model parameters through backpropagation during training. Then, an identical training phase might lead to different results.

Comment: There I didn't notice overfitting. As you explained, this improvement can be caused by the change of the model architecture and the weights.

Answer (score 4):

Stacking convolutions is equivalent to convolution, but with different filter size. It might be that the effectively bigger filter gives you different results, but there exists appropriately sized conv layer that is equivalent wiith two conv layers (if the boundary conditions are right)

Comment: can you share a good article to read about stacking convolutions (if it is possible)? In my model I have used <br/> `model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=input_size)) <br/>
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))` <br/> Also I want to know what is the effect of following layers <br/> `  model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')) <br/> model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))`

Comment: Nobody stacks convolutional layers without nonlinearities because of what I mentioned. To get the feeling of convolutions I encourage you to check out [guide to convolutional arithmetic](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic), find appropriate equations and do the math (you might want to check out some NN course that calculates number of weights of Conv layers to be sure).

Comment: yes @jakub. By mistake, I haven't used non-linearity layer between Conv layers, but it gave a good accuracy with good predictions. That is why, I thought whether this gives some effect to the model, because when I retrain the model after adding non-linearity layer, it didn't show better performance than previous. Thank you again for the guide, I follow this today it self.